# How to link already installed python to MSYS2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, msys2

I already have python 2.7 and 3.7 installed on my computer. I just don't want to re-download python using pacman.
Is there a way to link python with MSYS2?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Python in MSYS2, you need to use the one bundled with pacman. Mingw-64 compiles Python using GCC for Windows and it is heavily patched downstream so that it will run. You can't use the normal Windows Python that is compiled against Microsoft Visual C, it isn't compatible.